# Wubi installer  is taking ages to download

Tags: 12.04, wubi

I am downloading Ubuntu 12.04--Wubi installer but for reasons unknown, it is taking ages to download. I have no choice but to abort it. FYI, I have installed Wubi before but have uninstalled it not long ago.
Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: You can choose other option. http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/precise/

Comment: The Ubuntu Wubi installer is only 2.4Mb in size.
I suspect you mean that when you've executed the wubi installer, when it starts to download the Ubuntu packages it takes long?

Comment: You should report a bug.

Comment: Just download the ISO file separately and put it in the same folder as the wubi.exe executable. What kind of internet connection do you have?

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the [wubi.exe](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) file only (it is a relatively small executable). Do not run it, just download it.
2. Download the ISO image from [one of the many mirrors](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors), check which one will be fastest.
3. Put the ISO image **in the same folder** as the wubi.exe file.
4. Start wubi.exe and enjoy the blinking lights.